# QuickSort Analysis with Pivot as a last Element in Array

Tags: java, arrays, big-o, quicksort

I was wondering what the Big-O of this Array is when you use QuickSort:

```
6 8 7 5 9 4
```

`4` is my Pivot element.

I thought it would be Best-Case with a complexity of `O(nlogn)`, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Big-O does not really apply to a specific input or set of inputs. It is not useful to say "the Big-O for array `6 8 7 5 9 4` is O(n log n)". It's different levels of abstraction.

Comment: Big-O s not applicable to specific objects.

Answer (score 1):

The Big-O complexity of quicksort is quadratic (`O(n^2)`). this means that for every possible input, it will perform at least this fast (or slow, if you will).

As mentioned in comments, Big-O deals with theoretical worst-case scenario, not with a particular input. For a particular input, you can compute the absolute number of steps.

---

As an aside, quicksort is (was?) quite popular not for a good Big-O performance, but for good *usual case* performance on moderate input sizes - while there are algorithms that perform in `O(n log n)` (that's also theoretical limit - can't do better), they tended to be slower in practical use since they had larger *constants* (i.e. the *asymptotically* better performance only manifested itself on large inputs).